# Trigger "OK" on login by using Enter

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to press Enter on my keyboard for the "OK" button to activate on the login screen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWR2y.png).

At the moment when I press enter, the entered data on the textbox disappears.
I have the code all working for the "OK" button to be *clicked* but I would prefer if there was the availability of also pressing Enter. I have looked on other forums and haven't found the answer so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    Dim a As Integer = 0
    Dim attempt As Integer = 0

    'Added Username and Password settings for the Form "Login"

    If txtUsername.Text = My.Settings.Username Then
        a += 1
    End If

    If txtPassword.Text = My.Settings.Password Then
        a += 1
    End If

    If a = 2 Then
        'Login Successful message displayed if correct details are entered

        MsgBox("Login Successful", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

        Me.Hide()
        frmCustomerDetails.Show()
    Else
        'Login Unsuccessful message displayed if incorrect details are entered
        'Username and Password Text Fields are cleared to allow user to easily re-enter information

        Static cntAttempts = 0
        cntAttempts += 1
        If cntAttempts = 3 Then
            MsgBox("Login Failed Too Many Times: Exiting Application", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            Me.Close()
        End If

        MsgBox("Username or Password Incorrect", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        txtUsername.Clear()
        txtPassword.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OK-Cancel Dialog: handling the 'Enter' key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544867/ok-cancel-dialog-handling-the-enter-key-press) (Found by googling for "vb.net ok button enter".)

Comment: You know people re-use passwords, right? They're not supposed to, but they do anyway. This means the unencrypted password stored in your My.Setttings.Password field is probably also used for banking, email, facebook, etc. A breach of your user's computer now potentially exposes all those things. **You need to hash your passwords before you store them.** When the user tries to login you also hash the attempt, and then compare the hashes.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn This isn't a program for people to actually use and have their sensitive data on. This is a personal project. The username and password are set specifically and no other username or password will work. I will not be storing sensitive user data.

Comment: This is one of those things that's too important even for personal or learning projects. If you need to build authentication at all, you need to build it **right**. Again, it doesn't matter if this program doesn't keep sensitive data. The credentials people put here **WILL** for some users also be used other places that do keep sensitive data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the forms designer select the form. In the properties window under "Misc" select your OK button as `AcceptButton` and select your Cancel button as `CancelButton`.

This will make the OK button the default button with a bold border. It will be activated when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> unless another control with a default function attached to <kbd>Enter</kbd> has the focus (like another button).

When you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> this will activate the Cancel button.

Answer (score -1):

On my login my password textbox is named "TxtPass" on the keydown I have this code:

```
Private Sub TxtPass_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) _
    Handles txtPass.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Call CmdLogin_Click(sender, e)
    End If
End Sub
```

Usually a user will click on the button named CmdLogin but if instead he want to use the Enter key, it works as shown

Comment: Who uses the `Call` keyword anymore? It has no purpose at all in .Net except to save you a few seconds removing it when you port forward old vb6-era code.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Necessary when the called expression doesn't start with an identifier. `Call (Sub() Console.Write("Hello"))()`  

    `Call New TheClass().ShowText()`

Comment: Not good to Call an event procedure. You are sending a TextBox as sender to a click event that is a Button event. And sending KeyEventArgs to a parameter that is expecting EventArgs. Better is to make a separate method and call it from both places.